# How to get asp Dropdownlist selected value in c# file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a follow dropdown list in my `aspx` page:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="OrderPeriodStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
    CssClass="ddlb" Width="100px" Height="30px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" 
    DataTextField="OrderPeriod" DataValueField="OrderPeriodID" onselectedindexchanged="OrderPeriodStatus_SelectedIndexChanged">
     </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProdDB %> # blah blah query
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I tried to access the value of selected value in C# by following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ProcessEligibleScenarios();
            LoadOptions();
            ddlbPeriod.DataBind();
            GridView1.DataBind();
            gvActiveLogs.DataBind();
        }
    }

protected void OrderPeriodStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OrderPeriodStatus.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            SqlConnection myConn = default(SqlConnection);
            SqlCommand myComm = default(SqlCommand);
            myConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProdDB"].ConnectionString);
            myConn.Open();
            myComm = new SqlCommand("SELECT OrderPeriodDate, OrderPeriodStatus, Notes FROM OrderPeriod WHERE OrderPeriod ='" + OrderPeriodStatus.SelectedValue + "'");
            try
            {
                myComm.Connection = myConn;
                SqlDataReader Dr = myComm.ExecuteReader();
                while (Dr.Read())
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("While reading the data");
                    TextBox1.Text = Dr["OrderPeriodDate"].ToString();
                    TextBox2.Text = Dr["OrderPeriodStatus"].ToString();
                    NotesArea.Value = (string)Dr["Notes"];
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(OrderPeriodStatus.SelectedValue);
                }
                Dr.Close();
                myConn.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException sqx)
            {
            }
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else {  }
    }
```

But when i print the `value`. It shows the selected Index not the value. Why?

Comment: How do you know it's the selected index, not the value, being printed?  You are giving it the OrderID as the value, so SelectedValue returns the OrderID...  Where is that code where do you print the value?

Comment: Because when i choose the another data from the list. It shows the no of index

Comment: just mismatch error Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatch error on sqdatasource, replace with `SqlDataSource4`

```
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5"  <---

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProdDB %> # blah blah query
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: If dropdown is loosing its selected value then `DropDownListnew.SelectedValue` should return an empty string, But OP stats that he is getting `Index` instead of `Value`

Comment: Just because your Selected Value is binded on OrderID primary key, and your primary key is similar to index

Comment: It's already there :( I Have updated the question by including the page_load method and complete definition of onlick method

Comment: Sorry it was pasting mistake. Now i updated it, Now what should i do?

Comment: You can update and test , i think that's very good your implementation

Comment: Still it is returning the Index :(

Comment: it's not not your index but your primary key DataValueField="OrderPeriodID"

Comment: Aha! Thanks. It happend because of stress :P

Comment: Amit i understand i 'am happy to help you, i am here  if you need help, good luck Amit

Answer (score 0):

If you set AutoPostback property on the dropdownlist to true, and ViewStateMode to inherit, you should get value you selected. I tried it on my side, and it worked. Since you already have SqlDataSource, and the DataSourceId of the dropdownlist is set to the SqlDataSource, it should be populated automatically.

---edit

Sorry, I think I might have misread your question. If you instead use

```
DropDownListnew.SelectedItem.Text
```

you should get the text value you want.

-- another edit:

@Amit, you will get index from SelectedValue, because in your dropdownlist code, you have set

```
DataValueField="OrderPeriodID"
```

which is basically your primary key or index. To get the text value instead of index you have to use

```
SelectedItem.Text
```

Also in your query:

```
myComm = new SqlCommand("SELECT OrderPeriodDate, OrderPeriodStatus, Notes FROM OrderPeriod WHERE OrderPeriod ='" + OrderPeriodStatus.SelectedValue + "'");
```

I think you should be using

```
WHERE OrderPeriodID ='" + OrderPeriodStatus.SelectedValue + "'");
```

You are missing the ID bit after OrderPeriod.

Comment: You DataSourceId is wrong. It is set to SqlDataSource5 when it should be SqlDataSource4?

Answer (score 0):

You can try get the value from `Request.Form` object and to get the text use `ddl.Items.FindByValue` method

```
    var value = Request.Form[DropDownListnew.UniqeID];
    var text = DropDownListnew.Items.FindByValue(value);
```